# javascript regex money

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, json

I'm trying to remove the decimal values on a money value pulled from json feed:

if I have like: **150,000** I want to have just **150**

ere's my code:

```
$.getJSON('/static/js/datatest.json', function (result){

  $.each(result.events, function(i, item){
    $('#isoContainer').append('<h3>&pound;<span class="value">' + item.value.replace(/\.0{0,2}$/, "") + '</span></h3>');               
  });   
});
```

Why this is not working **`item.value.replace(/\,0{0,3}$/, "")`** ?

Comment: Your code uses a `{0,2}` limiter but you then (correctly) use `{0,3}` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you escape the comma, the correct version is

```
/,0{0,3}$/
```

or if it doesn't go to the end of line, just

```
/,0{0,3}/
```

EDIT:

if you can have nonzero values after the `,` this is the correct one instead

```
/,\d{0,3}/
```

EDIT 2:

Also check that in the 'culture' you are using the , means the start of decimal positions and not the thousands separator

Answer (score 0):

The code you've supplied uses a `.` in the regex, not a `,`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
"150,000".replace(/,(0|00|000)$/, "") // "150"
```

$ signifies end of string, other than that, it's plain simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `parseInt()`?

```
> parseInt("150,000");
150
> parseInt("150.000");
150
```